# Solr Exception when trying to integrate with liferay

Tags: solr, tomcat7, liferay-6

I trying to add apache solr 4.6 on window 7 with tomcat 7.

Also i added the solr, solrj and log4j  into tomcat lib folder.
I copied the solr web porlet into liferay and try to start the server but i am getting exception.

Can anyone tell me what this error is about.

> 15:01:24,325 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][HotDeployImpl:185]
>   Deploying solr-web from queue 15:01:24,326 INFO 
>   [localhost-startStop-1][PluginPackageUtil:1049] Reading plugin package
>   for solr-web 15:01:24,610 ERROR
>   [localhost-startStop-1][ContextLoader:227] Context initialization
>   failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/solr-spring.xml]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1002)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:906)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextLoaderListener.java:85)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:79)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:41)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:195)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:97)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.doInvoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:88)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.invoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:56)
>     at $Proxy29.fireDeployEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1672)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer   at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
>     ... 49 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer   at
>   com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer.(BasicAuthSolrServer.java:71)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer.(BasicAuthSolrServer.java:81)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer.(BasicAuthSolrServer.java:75)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     ... 59 more 15:01:24,623 ERROR
>   [localhost-startStop-1][HotDeployImpl:198]
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error
>   initializing Spring for solr-web
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error
>   initializing Spring for solr-web  at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:46)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:44)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:195)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:97)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.doInvoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:88)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.invoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:56)
>     at $Proxy29.fireDeployEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1672)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/solr-spring.xml]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1002)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:906)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextLoaderListener.java:85)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:79)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:41)
>     ... 32 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer   at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
>     ... 49 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer   at
>   com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer.(BasicAuthSolrServer.java:71)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer.(BasicAuthSolrServer.java:81)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.search.solr.server.BasicAuthSolrServer.(BasicAuthSolrServer.java:75)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solr-web plugin for liferay 6.1.x is not compatible with solr 4.6, it is compatible with solr 1.4.

If you want to use solr 4.6 you have to modify solr-web. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20427249/196134) to your other question on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer at 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass...
```

This error tells you the class ̀`org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer` wasn't found. There are several possibilities for this kind of error to happen.

1/ This class might be needed for a version of solrj different of the one you put in lib folder or there is a conflict between different version of librairies

2/ Tomcat Lib folder is not taken into account. Make sure this path is valid

3/ Tomcat PATH is not well defined. Startup scripts or executables are there to install paths and configure folders (at least on Linux, but it should be the same on Windows ;-) ). Check you start Tomcat in the recommended way

4/ You have added jars to lib folder and hot re-deployed the app. Restart tomcat for the JVM to take the new jars into account

By the way, these librairies are third party ones that have not to be installed for all Tomcat contexts. I recommend you as a good practice to add them to the webapps lib folder (`WEB-INF/lib` should do the trick) .
You'll then be sure not to have classloader on different branches on the classloader tree.

EDIT : I think this is a problem with your solr/solrj version. I found that in [Solrj 4.6 SVN](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_6_0/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/), there is no trace at all of a `CommonsHTTPSolrServer`
I think this class has been dropped since version 4.0 of Solr
The code that use the client should be upgraded to Solr 4 or your jar downgraded to 3.6.2 at most

Comment: is there any other possible reason?Is this might be related to version? i am using solr 4.6 and liferay 6.1.2 CE ga3 ...
 
because i  already checked all your recommendation...all of them are correctly implemented..

Comment: I've made a bit of research and I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: the jar related to solr 4.6 i added are slf4j-api-1.6.6,
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6,solr-core-4.6.0,solr-dataimporthandler-4.6.0,solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.6.0, solr-solrj-4.6.0

......Are you advicing me to move to lower version of solr like 4 and below?

Comment: I'm just saying that the classes taht are using the solrj client expect a "prior to solr 4.0" version. Maybe your version of the solr web portlet is too old. What is the version you use ? I can see on the web that you can integrate liferay with solr 4 in version 6.1.2 EE

Comment: Sorry, but I asked you about your Liferay version

Comment: Ok, after some googling, it seems to be really messy to integrate latest version of solr in Liferay. Liferay plugin seems to work with solr 1.4.1, and rework needs to be done (as I said) to make the plugin work with solr 4. You have 2 choices : rewrite the plugin or use solr 1.4.1. But a search 'solr liferay' on github gave me two [interesting](https://github.com/lukeskypator/solr-solrcloud4-web) [answers](https://github.com/JulienDeruere/liferay-solr) that both claim to integrate liferay 6.1+ with solr 4+