# Compatibility :Liferay 6.1.2 ce ga3 and solr 4.6

Tags: solr, liferay-6, solrj

> **Can any one tell me  liferay 6.1.2 ce ga3 on tomcat 7 and solr 4.6 on tomcat 7 are compatible?**

Used the solr web portlet avaible from liferay market.

I am working on this from last 3 days and i am still getting version issues,executing query issues ,SolrCore 'collection1' is not available  issues, CommonsHTTPSolrServer  even after following lot  of suggestion.

I tried all permutation regarding the jars.

slf4j-api-1.6.6

slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6

slf4j-simple-1.6.6

solr-common-1.3.0

solr-core-4.6.0

solr-solrj-4.6.0

httpclient-4.3.1

httpcore-4.3

httpmime-4.3.1

I also raised this issue on liferay support forum : https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42758

Comment: AFAIK it has support with solr 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not compatible (out of the box).
But it is doable, at least it is with Solr 4.4.0 and 4.5.1, so I would guess with Solr 4.6.0 also.

General steps to make it work:

**solr-web**

- download latest solr-web plugin (source) for 6.1.x
- modify dependacies (see below)
- modify source files (resolve compilation errors)
- modify solr-spring.xml (if needed)
- modify schema.xml (look at both liferay's and solr version, and "merge" (what makes sense) them)

**List of jars**

- commons-codec-1.6.jar
- commons-io-2.1.jar
- httpclient-4.2.3.jar
- httpcore-4.2.2.jar
- httpmime-4.2.3.jar
- noggit-0.5.jar
- portal-compat-shared.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- solr-solrj-4.5.1.jar
- wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
- zookeeper-3.4.5.jar (probably could be removed, I did not)

Additional (provided) jars not packaged in war

- portal-service-6.1.1.jar
- util-java-6.1.1.jar
- servlet-api-2.5.jar

**Specifically for CommonsHTTPSolrServer ClassNotFoundException**

- in BasicAuthSolrServer constructor you should use HttpSolrServer, instead of CommonsHTTPSolrServer